# Formatting date and time with zapier on javascript

Tags: javascript, zapier

I try to write this code to pass in a time and format it. It works on my IDE but when I pass it to zapier, it has an error.
This is my code

```
 function dateConvert(dateobj,format){
  var year = dateobj.getFullYear();
  var month= ("0" + (dateobj.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
  var date = ("0" + dateobj.getDate()).slice(-2);
  var hours = ("0" + dateobj.getHours()).slice(-2);
  var minutes = ("0" + dateobj.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
  var seconds = ("0" + dateobj.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
  var day = dateobj.getDay();
  var months = ["JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC"];
  var dates = ["SUN","MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT"];
  var converted_date = "";

  switch(format){
    case "YYYY-MM-DD":
      converted_date = year + "-" + month + "-" + date;
      break;
    case "YYYY-MMM-DD DDD":
      converted_date = year + "-" + months[parseInt(month)-1] + "-" + date + " " + dates[parseInt(day)];
      break;
  }

  return converted_date;
}
var date = input.VIP_2bParsed;
var format = "YYYY-MMM-DD DDD";
var converted_day = dateConvert(date,format);

output={converted_day: converted_day}
```

I have the following error: TypeError: dateobj.getFullYear is not a function
Full image of error here [ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8runR.png)

Answer (score 1):

Is `VIP_2bParsed` a variable you mapped in the Zap editor? If so, you'll want to access it with `inputData.VIP_2bParsed` instead of `input.VIP_2bParsed`.